# Spitting a column based on a delimiter

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to extract some information from a column in my dataframe:

Example

```
Col
7 points  — it is an example ...
13 points  — as above ...
some other text ...
1 point  — "what to say more?"
13 points  — ...
11 points  — 1234 ...
```

I was using str.contain to extract the first part (i.e., all the information before the first dash, where there is.

```
m = (df['Col'].str.contains(r'(?i)^\d+\spoint | points'))
df[m]
```

I am still getting the same original column (so no extraction). My output would consist in two columns, one without points information (Col1) and another one (Col2) with the text extracted.

```
Col1
7 points  
13 points 
# need to still keep the row, even if empty
1 point 
13 points
11 points
```

and

```
Col2       
it is an example ...
as above ...
some other text ...
"what to say more?"
...                                                   
1234 ...
```

It is important to consider the first dash where there is, since I might have more dash included in the text.
It seems to be this symbol `-`, but maybe it can be a *longer* dash. I copied and pasted from my dataset, but copying it here it seems to be slightly different.

Comment: have you tried `str.extract()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `str.extract` with Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df[['Col1', 'Col2']] = df['Col'].str.extract(r"(\d+ points?)?\s*\—?\s*(.*)", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                Col       Col1                  Col2
0  7 points  — it is an example ...   7 points  it is an example ...
1         13 points  — as above ...  13 points          as above ...
2               some other text ...        NaN   some other text ...
3    1 point  — "what to say more?"    1 point   "what to say more?"
4                  13 points  — ...  13 points                   ...
5             11 points  — 1234 ...  11 points              1234 ...
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh.  In case of multiple terms (for example points/point or score/scores before the delimiter), as I could change it? For instance, I might have `1 point - ....` but also `10 score - bla bla bla` within the same column.

Comment: `(\d+ points?|\d+ scores?)?\s*\—?\s*(.*)` ?

Answer (score 3):

#### `Series.str.split`

We can split the column `Col` around the delimiter `\s—\s` and limit the number of splits to `1` in order to avoid splitting on multiple occurrences of `\s—\s`

```
df[['Col1', 'Col2']] = df['Col'].str.split(r'\s—\s', n=1, expand=True)
```

---

```
                                Col        Col1                  Col2
0  7 points  — it is an example ...   7 points   it is an example ...
1         13 points  — as above ...  13 points           as above ...
2    1 point  — "what to say more?"    1 point    "what to say more?"
3                  13 points  — ...  13 points                    ...
4             11 points  — 1234 ...  11 points               1234 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Shubham Sharma. I noticed that in case of no -, some text is lost in the original dataset. I have got None instead of the text.  In the example above would have been happened with the case of `some other text ...` . Could you please check if this happens to you as well?

Comment: @Val We are not loosing any text actually all then text will be present in the first column in case there is no `-`..But if you want the text to be in column `2` then we might have to use `extract` as shown by @Rakesh in his answer.